# What is an aerostatic globe?

Tags: meaning

Whenever I try to google it I get redirected to "Hot Air Balloon". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_air_balloon

What's weirder is that there is not a single mention of "aerostatic globe" in the "hot air balloon" wiki itself.

To be honest, I've always called the hot air balloons, aerostatic globes. But I don't really know where I originally got this name from.

Searching for "aerostatic globe" inside quotations will show me images of what seem to be very old hot air balloons.

Are aerostatic globes just old hot air balloons?

Comment: Aerostatic implies hovering, and a sphere or globe is a logical shape for a balloon. It sounds like something you'd see in an early translation of Jules Verne.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected when I commented, the origin seems to be French. Wikipedia's (English) article on the [Montgolfier brothers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgolfier_brothers) refers to their *globe aérostatique*. The English phrase would then be a literal translation.

The French phrase is used in [this 1783 illustration](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:1783_balloonj.jpg) of the first flight in the brothers' balloon.

Around the same time :

> An anonymous author writing as a Mr. Vivenair published A Journey Lately Performed Through the Air in an Aerostatic Globe, Commonly Called an Air Balloon, From This Terraquaeous Globe to the Newly Discovered Planet, Georgium Sidus in 1784. [Wikipedia, *Uranus in fiction*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranus_in_fiction)

While the author's pseudonym and narrator and apparently French, this satire on the court of King George III has been [presumed to be written by a British author](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/vivenair_monsieur); it was published in London, in English.

Comment: I see, but that leaves me wondering, "aerostatic globe" is probably wrong, right? Even if it's the literal translation of the word in other languages (I also tried it in Spanish, same translation pops up).

Comment: Given the *Vivenair* source I would say it's an archaic term that never really took off. So it's not useful in modern settings but if, for example, you were worrying a story set in the late 18th or early 19th century, especially in France, it might be suitable.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I'll probably just stick to the Hot Air Balloon term, even though the other one sounds way cooler.